# Angular, strange error Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error using APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, firefox

I want use `APP_INITIALIZER` for load security info from backend, when angular application started. I add `APP_INITIALIZER` in `AppModule`:

```
 providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: init,
            deps: [AuthService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
```

My init function:

```
export function init(authService: AuthService) {
    return () => {
        return authService.loadSecurityInfo(true).toPromise();
    };
}
```

Method `loadSecurityInfo` look like this:

```
loadSecurityInfo(reconstituteSecurity = false): Observable<SecurityInfo> {
    console.log(`Loading SecurityInfo - Reconstitute security? ${reconstituteSecurity}`);

    return this.http
        .get<any>(this.securityInfoUrl, {headers: this.headers})
        .pipe(
            map(body => {
                this._securityInfo = new SecurityInfo();
                this._securityInfo.isAuthenticationEnabled = body.authenticationEnabled;
                this._securityInfo.isAuthenticated = body.authenticated;
                this._securityInfo.username = body.username;
                this._securityInfo.roles = body.roles as string[];

                console.log(`Getting security info: ${JSON.stringify(this.securityInfo)}`);
                return this._securityInfo;
            }),
            catchError(this.errorReporter.handleError('loadSecurityInfo', null))
        );
}
```

When I run the app and try to refresh the page by pressing F5 quickly for example two times, I get an error in browser console:

```
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
loadSecurityInfo failed: Backend returned code 0, status: undefined, error list: undefined
zUnb/Y</e.prototype.handleError/<
http://localhost:8080/main.ba74b710245ba9a3c361.js:1:1433305
9Z1F/u</t.prototype.error
m
http://localhost:8080/polyfills.855d06b353079dbdbf17.js:1:20756
b
```

If I press F5 slowly when the previous page refresh worked, there is no error! I broke my brain, why is this mistake happening? The error occurs **only** in the `Firefox browser 60.4.0 esr` is possible and below, on the latest versions of `Firefox` and `Chrome` no errors. Any help.

I use `Angular 6.1.10`

Comment: Did you found solution on this issue? I'm facing similar issue with APP_INITIALIZER in firefox.